# Erratic and slow behavior with create-react-app and Skaffold kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I have Skaffold working well with local development server and database deployments. I'm trying to get working on the `create-react-app` front-end, but the behavior is incredibly slow and erratic.

**Issues**

The main problems are the following:

1. It takes upwards of five minutes from running `skaffold dev --port-forward --tail` for it finally start spinning up. Running just a `docker build` takes less than 30 seconds.
2. When it finally starts spinning up, it just sits on `Starting the development server...` for another two minutes.
3. Then, nine times out of ten, I get the following errors after several minutes (there are three because that is how many replicas there are):
   [image]

   One out of ten times, it will actually go into the `Compiled Successfully! You can now view in the browser.` It never does launch in Chrome though.
4. Changes to JS in create-react-app are never reflected in new browser. You have to stop and run Skaffold again. Skaffold does say `Syncing 1 files for <image>... Watching for changes...`, but nothing changes even after a refresh.

**What I've tried**

1. I've really simplified what I'm trying to do to make it easier to sort this out, so I'm using just an OOTB `create-react-app` application. The behavior is the same regardless.
2. `minikube delete` and `minikube start` several times (did this because even the server deployment started acting erratically after trying `create-react-app`)

**Code and Steps to Reproduce**

I'm on macOS Mojave (10.14.6) using Docker for Mac, Kubernetes (v1.16.0), minikube (v1.4.0), Skaffold (v0.39.0), and `create-react-app`. I'll have to skip the installation process for all of these since it is fairly lengthy, so the following steps assume you have this already setup.

1. Make a project directory:

   `mkdir project`
2. Make a Kubernetes manifest directory and move into it:

   `mkdir k8s && cd k8s`
3. Make a `client-deployment.yaml` and add the following:

   ```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: client-deployment
   spec:
     replicas: 3
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         component: web
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           component: web
       spec:
         containers:
           - name: client
             image: testapp/client
             ports:
               - containerPort: 3000
   ```
4. Make a `client-cluster-ip-service.yaml` and add the following:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: client-cluster-ip-service
   spec:
     type: ClusterIP
     selector:
       component: web
     ports:
       - port: 3000
         targetPort: 3000
   ```
5. Move back into the parent:

   `cd ..`
6. Create a `skaffold.yaml` and add the following:

   ```
   apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta15
   kind: Config
   build:
     local:
       push: false
     artifacts:
       - image: testapp/client
         context: web
         docker:
           dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
         sync:
           manual:
             - src: "**/*.js"
               dest: .
             - src: "**/*.html"
               dest: .
             - src: "**/*.css"
               dest: .
   deploy:
     kubectl:
       manifests:
         - k8s/client-deployment.yaml
         - k8s/client-cluster-ip-service.yaml
   portForward:
     - resourceType: service
       resourceName: client-cluster-ip-service
       port: 3000
       localPort: 3000
   ```
7. Start a new `create-react-app` project:

   `npx create-react-app test-app`
8. Change into the directory:

   `cd test-app`
9. Create a `Dockerfile.dev` and add the following:

   ```
   FROM node:alpine

   WORKDIR '/app'
   EXPOSE 3000
   CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

   COPY package* ./
   RUN npm install
   COPY . .
   ```
10. Create a `.dockerignore` file and add the following:

    ```
    node_modules
    *.swp
    ```
11. Go back into the parent directory:

    `cd ..`
12. Make sure `minikube` is running:

    `minikube start`
13. Run the `skaffold.yaml`:

    `skaffold dev --port-forward --tail`

This is what produces the issues for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. Disregard. Started with one replica and it worked fine. Two worked fine. Three worked if `skaffold` was already running, but not from a fresh `skaffold dev --port-forward --tail`.

`skaffold ssh` and then did a `top`. Was running out of RAM... well was at 86% utilization. Increased it from the default 2GB to 8GB and now it works fine.

First deleted the VM with `minikube delete` and then created a new one with `minikube start --memory='8g'`. All good now.